# не могу решить задачу на python

Tags: python

нужно найти сумму чисел list["3","4","1","8","-7","20","85"] через for

Comment: Отвечающие на этом сайте ставят минусы и закрывают вопросы, если они напоминают ТЗ. Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос [**собственными попытками**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) справиться с заданием. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных вопрос плох, но не нужно ложь распространять, как я вам уже неоднократно говорил. Говорите за себя.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 0
seq = ["3","4","1","8","-7","20","85"]

for k in map(int, seq):
    s += k
print(s)
```

Comment: Или так `sum(map(int,seq))` :)
Кто короче? ^_^

Comment: @nobody ты конечно) просто он попросил написать через for